# How to forward all packets to another subnet?

Tags: centos, iptables, aws

I am trying to send a copy of all packets to another ip that is not the same subnet. Let's say I want to send a copy of all traffic from 10.0.1.100 to 10.0.2.100. I have another IP, 10.0.1.101 that will be between 10.0.1.100 and 10.0.2.100.

I will use iptables to send a copy of traffic on 10.0.1.100 to 10.0.1.101 since TEE can only be used to send packets to an IP on the same subnet.

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j TEE --gateway 10.0.1.101
```

I need to then send those copied packets to 10.0.2.100. How can I do that without modifying header info? I have looked into TPROXY, but I don't know enough about it to know if that is the correct solution.

The OS is CentOS 7. This will be used in AWS. I need to preserve the source and dest info in the headers, if possible.

Comment: I didn't try but I think if you configure 1.101 so that you can reach from 1.100 to 2.100 through 1.101 (i.e. can send ping), writing rule as "--gateway 10.0.2.100" should work

Comment: If you mean set the gateway in the mangle rules for TEE and set the gateway to .2.100, the gateway must not be more than one hop away. The only way to make that work would be change the subnet to include both addresses. If that is not what you meant, could you expand on it?

Comment: That was what I meant:). So why don't you give your subnet mask as /16

Comment: The system it is simulating has a separate subnet for each instance with a network policy to whitelist connections between subnets through AWS security groups. This simulation does not employ a white list and allows all communication. Changing the cidr would change the entire implementation.

Comment: I see. then maybe another option is recording pcap and send them with rsync. but that would cost you permanent disk operation

Comment: how is the IP 10.0.1.101 "between" 10.0.1.100 and 10.0.2.100 ? does it have a presence with an other interface on 10.0.2.0/24 (eg: with IP 10.0.2.101)? Is there a router not described? Can you clarify?